# Kill the signed tag

Tags: support, burninate-request

The [signed](/questions/tagged/signed) tag on StackOverflow is too ambiguous. It can refer to a signed Java applet, signed integer, signed Facebook application, Signed Android application, Signed CF Request, etc. There are much better ways of expressing the aforementioned concepts rather than just the generic [signed](/questions/tagged/signed) tag. There are [282 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signed) tagged signed.

Comment: All of your examples but "signed integer" is the same concept ("signed application").

Comment: @EmilVikström: Signed Cold Fusion request aka message signing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921362/coldfusion-cfhttp-with-sha512-hmac-signed-rest-request-body

Comment: Retag the Application Signing and Message Signing questions as needed, and put a tag wiki on the signed tag.

Comment: [tag:sign] has got the same problem.